# Client ask linkedIn contact for employee who doesn't want to share it

Tags: linkedin, clients

I just joined a maintenance project.  For every new people joining the project, the client immediately asks the firstname and lastname of the newcomer and ask them as relation on LinkedIn. He said that he likes knowing who works with him. The others developers on the project didn't mind and accepted the invitation.

I don't want to accept the relation (and it is its right) but don't know how to tell the client.

Do you have any advice on how I could politely decline the LinkedIn invitation? I feel like we owe a polite explanation.

> Sorry Mr XXX, but I keep my LinkedIn contact for work relation

The sentence seems bad as we are somehow work related.

Is it better to accept the invitation then delete it discretely some days after?

Comment: Why doesn't your colleague want to accept? The entire purpose of LinkedIn is networking with work contacts, which includes your client.

Comment: For personal reason. Let's say for example, that the customer works in the army and that is not right with its personal values

Comment: WIth all due respect, your client sounds either too creepy or immature. Hasn't he got better things to do than adding *every* person he works with?

Comment: Did the client actually approach you in person asking to add you as a LinkedIn friend? Or was it purely through the LinkedIn interface -- as I recall from logging in, they usually give you a big list of "suggestions", so he may have just clicked on your photo without having given the "invitation" much thought.

Comment: @bradin through linked in but he did ask my lastname by the first reunion

Answer (score 5):

Accept and remove later if s/he wants. Better to do that than piss off a client. Honestly, not sharing on LinkedIn with someone you're working with makes no sense. It's not facebook, the whole point is networking and building a network.

Honestly, if he doesn't want to share it with clients, he shouldn't have LinkedIn so he can just say "Oh, I don't have one."

Comment: Or he could create another LinkedIn specifically for this instance (more work involved, sure, but makes for a clean separation from the other account)

Comment: That's very true, but IMHO it would look kind of weird because searching for the name might show the same person twice which could raise questions with the client. "Hey, Fred do you have 2 LinkedIn profiles?" which would force him to lie in one way or another.

Comment: Having a LinkedIn account doesn't mean you have to add every random guy who you worked with once upon a time. I choose who goes in my LinkedIn list, I don't want my list to be polluted with people who I don't even remember.

Comment: @MaskedMan So do I, but a client doesn't really qualify as "every random guy".

Comment: Yeah but that is not really the point. I want to pick who is listed as a contact in LinkedIn, and I shouldn't have to put any unwanted people there.

Comment: And as the other answer mentions, you don't have to. Give him your name and then just ignore the request. "Oh, I don't get on LinkedIn hardly ever, sorry"

Answer (score 5):

Accepting a LinkedIn request is neither compulsory nor one that needs an explanation. If your colleague does not want to accept the request, for whatever reason, then they need not reply as to why. Moreover, it would be inappropriate for the company or a colleague to issue a reason why the invitation was not accepted, as it is regarding your colleague's social media usage, not yours or the employer's.